# Silverlight, TextBlock inside Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight

I'm totally new to silverlight and I was given a task to modify it. My problem is very simple (if done in asp.net webforms).
Basically, in the grid, i want to append year to something like this.

```
Jan + "-" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString()

Feb + "-" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString()
```

etc..etc..

The xaml looks like this

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0">
                <Grid.Resources>

<DataTemplate x:Key="mykey1">
                        <Grid >....</Grid>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="mykey2">
                        <Grid >....</Grid>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="mykey3">
                        <Grid >
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
<Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource LogicaPebbleBlackBrush}" BorderThickness="1">
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Style="{StaticResource HeaderStackPanel}">


<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlock}" Text="Jan-2013" Width="75" TextAlignment="Center"/>
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlock}" Text="Feb-2013" Width="75" TextAlignment="Center"/>


</StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
</Grid>
</DataTemplate>
</ Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

I just want to make the year dynamic so it changes yearly. Please help.

Comment: Can't you give your TextBlocks an ID and set their `.Text` property in the code-behind?

Comment: I tried but I can't access them in code behind.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can be done directly in XAML.

This is best done using binding.  In Silverlight, you *bind* most data sources to a property in code-behind (i.e. ViewModel).

In a nutshell:

1. Set DataContext of page to a code-behind class (typically a ViewModel)
2. ViewModel must implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface
3. Bind the text of your TextBox to use a Date property in the ViewModel that does the calculation in code

Once you have your DataContext setup, you can write XAML as follows:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Year, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Your ViewModel property will look as follows:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DateTime _year = DateTime.Now;
    public DateTime Year
    {
        get { return _year; }    // <--- append whatever here or in the setter
        set
        {
            _year = value; 

            if( this.PropertyChanged != null )
            {
                this.PropertyChanged( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( "Year" ) );
            }
         }
     }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.  It's xaml only:

```
<Grid.Resources>
      <System:DateTime  x:Key="DateTimeDataSource"/>
</Grid.Resources>

<TextBlock DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource DateTimeDataSource}}" 
      Text="{Binding Today.Year}">
</TextBlock>
```

Make sure you add this namespace:

```
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

You can display other DateTime properties too:  Now.Day, Today.Month, etc.

Comment: I'm having error. System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: Unknown element: DateTime. [Line: 29 Position: 66]

Line 29 points to <System:DateTime  x:Key="DateTimeDataSource"/>

Comment: Have you added this to your namespace and do you have it referenced in your project?  xmlns:System="clr namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"

Answer (score 0):

I reread your question and i think you need to do something like this.
Since your are working in a grid it is possible to name your textblocks.

```
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlock}" x:Name="JanTB" Width="75" TextAlignment="Center"/>
```

In your behind code it should be enough to place a text inside the textblock.

```
    JanTB.Text = "Jan-" + Datetime.now.Year.ToString();
```

I hope this solves your question.