# Add a tooltip to a textbox in a grid in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

```
<Grid>
<Canvas>

<TextBox Name="txt" IsReadOnly="True" Width="620" VerticalAlignment="Center"
Canvas.Left="340" Canvas.Top="5" Text="{Binding RowTitle2,Mode=OneWay}"    
ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding Path=Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
TextWrapping="NoWrap" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>

</Canvas>
</Grid>
```

this way there is no tooltip, so how to add one ?
here i create dynamically records(txtboxes in the grid)

but on a similar example everything works just fine(no dynamilcall creation of txtboxes)

```
<Grid>
<Canvas>

  <TextBox Name="txt" Margin="0,5,5,0" IsReadOnly="True" Width="620" VerticalAlignment="Center"
  Canvas.Left="-200" Canvas.Top="-5" 
ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding Path=Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
TextWrapping="NoWrap" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>

</Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12840147/silverlight-textblock-inside-grid and http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/37db1d/creating-tooltip-in-silverlight/

Comment: @Rachel Gallen as I wrote above In a simple case, yes i see the tooltip, but in my case when you dynamically create grids, I can't see the tooltip, I can't even see a simple ToolTipService.ToolTip="This is my tooltip" text  you just cant see it...

Comment: i suggest you look at this link then http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/f7dde9f1-e5eb-4ed0-a433-76d25f9b3362

Comment: The problem vas in canvas, somehow it was hiding the tooltip message, and also after the first canvas the wqas a second one which as partially hiding the tolltip message as well

Comment: aha! glad you resolved it. ...

Answer (score 0):

What's the point here ? Its a bit confusing to use ReadOnly text box in a canvas which is located in a grid. Instead use a TextBlock which also improves performance, prevents memory leak, and looks better.

```
    <Grid>
  <TextBlock Margin="0,5,5,0" 
VerticalAlignment="Center" 
HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
TextWrapping="NoWrap"
Text="{Binding RowTitle2}"
ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding Path=Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
 />
</Grid>
```